# Como fazer para aparecer o ícone do logo da empresa na caixa de mensagem do outlook

Tags: php, envio-de-email, outlook, newsletter

Tenho um código de disparo de email usando Zend.

```
$mailTransport = new Zend_Mail_Transport_Smtp($this->smtp_host, $config);

$mail = new Zend_Mail('UTF-8');
$mail->setFrom($from['email'], $from['name']);
$mail->addTo($to);
$mail->setSubject($subject);
$mail->setBodyHtml($bodyHtml);
$mail->send($mailTransport);
```

Na imagem abaixo, veja que o Meetup, tem um ícone... quando eles enviam um e-mail marketing. Enquanto a maioria só tem as iniciais, como o Mercado Livre "ML". Como poderia personalizar isso nas minhas mensagens.

Existe alguma API para isso?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: esses avatares são setados pelos provadores de e-mail e não pelo e-mail propriamente dito. qual seu provedor de email?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Até onde sei ai ele mostra a imagem que está na conta do e-mail. O ML não deve aparecer porque provavelmente não tem.

Tente inserir uma foto na conta de e-mail que está como remetente dessas mensagens.

Comment: Cara, era isso mesmo.

Answer (score 4):

Primeiramente pode não funcionar para todos os casos, pelo que testei e pesquisei somente para:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O Conceito é o mesmo que aparece aqui no Gmail.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Aqui o icone sozinho: [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

## Pequena descrição

Eles são referidos internamente como goomoji, e eles parecem ser uma extensão UTF-8 não padrão. Quando o Gmail encontra um desses caracteres, ele é substituído pelo ícone correspondente. Não consegui encontrar nenhuma documentação sobre eles, mas consegui engenharia reversa do formato.

**Então, como isso funciona?**

Sabemos que, de alguma forma, `876Urg==`significa o ícone `52E`, mas como?

Se nós decodamos base64 `876Urg==`, nós conseguimos 0xf3be94ae. Isso se parece com o seguinte em binário:

```
11110011 10111110 10010100 10101110
```

Esses bits são consistentes com um caractere codificado UTF-8 de 4 bytes.

```
11110xxx 10xxxxxx 10xxxxxx 10xxxxxx
```

Assim, os bits relevantes são os seguintes .:

```
  011   111110   010100   101110
```

Ou quando alinhado:

```
00001111 11100101 00101110
```

Em hexadecimal, esses bytes são os seguintes:

```
FE52E
```

Como você pode ver, com exceção do FEprefixo que é presumivelmente distinguir os goomojiícones de outros caracteres UTF-8, ele corresponde 52Eao ícone URL. Alguns testes comprovam que isso é válido para outros ícones.

## Parece muito trabalho, existe conversor?

Isso, claro, pode ser roteado. Criei o seguinte código Python para o meu teste. Essas funções podem converter a seqüência codificada base64 de e para a string hexadecimal curta encontrada no URL. Observe que este código está escrito para Python 3 e não é compatível com Python 2.

Funções de conversão:

```
import base64

def goomoji_decode(code):
    #Base64 decode.
    binary = base64.b64decode(code)
    #UTF-8 decode.
    decoded = binary.decode('utf8')
    #Get the UTF-8 value.
    value = ord(decoded)
    #Hex encode, trim the 'FE' prefix, and uppercase.
    return format(value, 'x')[2:].upper()

def goomoji_encode(code):
    #Add the 'FE' prefix and decode.
    value = int('FE' + code, 16)
    #Convert to UTF-8 character.
    encoded = chr(value)
    #Encode UTF-8 to binary.
    binary = bytearray(encoded, 'utf8')
    #Base64 encode return end return a UTF-8 string. 
    return base64.b64encode(binary).decode('utf-8')
```

Exemplos:

```
print(goomoji_decode('876Urg=='))
print(goomoji_encode('52E'))
```

Saída:

```
52E
876Urg==
```

> E, claro, encontrar o URL de um ícone simplesmente requer a criação de
> um novo rascunho no Gmail, inserindo o ícone desejado e usando o
> inspetor de DOM do seu navegador.

---

**Referências:**

https://blog.mailchimp.com/how-we-set-up-emoji-support-for-subject-lines/

https://www.campaignmonitor.com/resources/guides/using-emojis-and-symbols-in-email-marketing/

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28095387/animated-icon-in-email-subject

https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/outlook/4437-outlook-emoji-symbols-in-subject-line.html

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/Data_URIs

Comment: Valeu pelo esforço! Mas acredito que é algo mais simples. Como disse o @WendelRodrigues